# Graylog and ELB

Tags: amazon-elb, graylog

We are trying to use ELB to load balance two graylog nodes.  For the most part it works correctly but for certain actions like going to System-Nodes it times out and we receive the following.  If we go to the URL in logs directly we see an HTTP 405 error.

AWS indicates this means `Cause: The length of the method in the request header exceeds 127 characters` but other than checking the header length does not offer any solutions.

Does anyone have suggestions on trying to solve this?

```
[ProxiedResource] Unable to call https://URL:12900/system/metrics/multiple on node <153cd269-ce5c-400a-87b6-557235448be7>, caught exception: connect timed out (class java.net.SocketTimeoutException)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a workaround in place by putting my public DNS name in the hosts file of each graylog server pointing to it's local IP.